# execute ajax after enter and press button

Tags: javascript, ajax

i have  easy ajax script, which send data from form, it work this button, and i want to date send when i press enter, how i can make it? Very thanks!

ajax code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.ajaxSubmit').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: "{{ url('/names') }}",
                method: 'get',
                data: {
                    runBy: $(this).closest("form").find(".name").val(),
                    command: $(this).closest("form").find(".surname").val(),
                },
                success: function() {
                    location.reload();
                }
            });
    });
});
```

php code

```
  <form>
       <input type="hidden" value="{{Auth::user()?->name}}" class="name">
        <textarea class="surname" name="input" cols="30" rows="1"> </textarea>
        <button class="ajaxSubmit" onclick="event.preventDefault()">send</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: I don't quite understand your question, you want the date/time sent with the form? Or do want the form to be sent when you press enter?

Comment: I need that when I enter a value in the textbox and press enter on the keyboard, my script starts working and the form is sent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your Ajax submission code to a separate function. Add the Keypress event to the input element. Call that function from the keypress event when the keypress value is 13. Below is the code for your reference.

```
$('.input').keypress(function (e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    // Call the callback function
    return false;
  }
});
```

call the same Ajax function from a button click.

Regards,
omi